# How to Replace a specific char in a Varchar2 on Select

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, newline

I have a `VARCHAR2` that I want to `Select`, but it's too long. So, I want to `Split` it into multiples lines like this.

```
SELECT 'Veuillez adresser toute la correspondance à :  Aktiva2 Service Comptabilité : 30 B rue de la Petite Hollande 59700 Marcq-en-Baroeul Tel : 03 20 20 34 83@RET@IMPORTANT: pour faciliter nos échanges comptables, lors de votre paiement, par chèque et en particulier par virement, merci de rappeler votre n° de client et n° de facture acquittée.@RET@@RET@Paiement comptant sans escompte même en cas de paiement anticipé. Au-delà de 10 jours, une pénalité de 3 fois le taux d''intérêt légal (Loi 2008-776 du 04 août 2008) sera appliquée, calculée au prorata temporis sur la valeur de facture.  @RET@@RET@Conforment à la loi du 29 février 2012 le montant de l''indemnité forfaitaire pour frais de recouvrement est de 40 euros dans le cas où les sommes dues sont réglées après la date de règlement figurant sur la facture.'
FROM dual
```

Now I want to replace **@RET@** with something to jump into a 'new line' here. The result must be like this:

```
Veuillez adresser toute la correspondance à :  Aktiva2 Service Comptabilité : 30 B rue de la Petite Hollande 59700 Marcq-en-Baroeul Tel : 03 20 20 34 83

IMPORTANT: pour faciliter nos échanges comptables, lors de votre paiement, par chèque et en particulier par virement, merci de rappeler votre n° de client et n° de facture acquittée.

Paiement comptant sans escompte même en cas de paiement anticipé. Au-delà de 10 jours, une pénalité de 3 fois le taux d''intérêt légal (Loi 2008-776 du 04 août 2008) sera appliquée, calculée au prorata temporis sur la valeur de facture. 
<p>Conforment à la loi du 29 février 2012 le montant de l''indemnité forfaitaire pour frais de recouvrement est de 40 euros dans le cas où les sommes dues sont réglées après la date de règlement figurant sur la facture.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
declare text varchar2(1000);
begin
SELECT 'Veuillez adresser toute la correspondance à :  Aktiva2 Service Comptabilité : 30 B rue de la Petite Hollande 59700 Marcq-en-Baroeul Tel : 03 20 20 34 83@RET@IMPORTANT: pour faciliter nos échanges comptables, lors de votre paiement, par chèque et en particulier par virement, merci de rappeler votre n° de client et n° de facture acquittée.@RET@@RET@Paiement comptant sans escompte même en cas de paiement anticipé. Au-delà de 10 jours, une pénalité de 3 fois le taux d''intérêt légal (Loi 2008-776 du 04 août 2008) sera appliquée, calculée au prorata temporis sur la valeur de facture.  @RET@@RET@Conforment à la loi du 29 février 2012 le montant de l''indemnité forfaitaire pour frais de recouvrement est de 40 euros dans le cas où les sommes dues sont réglées après la date de règlement figurant sur la facture.'
into text from dual;
select REPLACE(text,'@RET@',chr(10)) into text from dual;
insert into testtable (col_text) values(text);
end;
/
```

This select will place spaces

```
select REPLACE(text,'@RET@',chr(10)) into text from dual;
```

Comment: can i make 2 replaces in the same time ?

Comment: select REPLACE(text,'@RET@',chr(10) && text,'@SAMTHING@','otherThing') into text from dual;

Comment: @Moudiz - Why PL/SQL when you could do it in plain SQL?

Comment: i want do it directly on the select

Comment: @LalitKumarB I am more familiar with pl sql though your answer is simple and Its good

Comment: @zebiridjallil you can select more then once.. replace the word @ret@ then replace it with another word .. is that what you wnat ?

Comment: @Moudiz - You shouldn't do in PL/SQL if you could do the same in pure SQL. PL/SQL and SQL are different engines.

Comment: @LalitKumarB yes you are right about that I though he is using plsql .. anyway if he is using sql your answer will help him

Comment: @Moudiz - You could edit your answer and add the following details: 1> PL/SQL varchar2 limit is 32767 bytes. 2> You could directly assign the value to the variable `text`, select into is not required. Good luck!

Comment: @LalitKumarB I appreciat your comments , and this answer was a quick example for the user to achieve his needs.

Answer (score 1):

CHR(10) is a new line

so `REPLACE(text,'@RET@',chr(10))`

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL function `REPLACE`:

```
replace(your_column, '@RET@', chr(13) || chr(10))
```

13 and 10 are the ASCII codes for CR and LF.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **REPLACE**. It depends on your OS whether to use only CHR(10) or both CHR(10) and CHR(13).

- **CHR(10)** - Line feed
- **CHR(13)** - Carriage return.

For windows:

`chr(10) || chr(13)`

For most of other OS:

`chr(10)`

For example, in my windows machine:

```
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'Veuillez adresser toute la correspondance à :  Aktiva2 Service Comptabilité : 30 B rue de la Petite Hollande 59700 Marcq-en-Baroeul Tel : 03 20 20 34 83@RET@IMPORTANT: pour faciliter nos échanges comptables,
 lors de votre paiement, par chèque et en particulier par virement, merci de rappeler votre n° de client et n° de facture acquittée.@RET@@RET@Paiement comptant sans escompte même en cas de paiement anticipé. Au-delà de 1
0 jours, une pénalité de 3 fois le taux d''intérêt légal (Loi 2008-776 du 04 août 2008) sera appliquée, calculée au prorata temporis sur la valeur de facture.  @RET@@RET@Conforment à la loi du 29 février 2012 le montant
de l''indemnité forfaitaire pour frais de recouvrement est de 40 euros dans le cas où les sommes dues sont réglées après la date de règlement figurant sur la facture.' str
  3  FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT REPLACE(str, '@RET@', chr(10)) text FROM DATA;

TEXT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Veuillez adresser toute la correspondance à :  Aktiva2 Service Comptabilité : 30 B rue de la Petite
Hollande 59700 Marcq-en-Baroeul Tel : 03 20 20 34 83
IMPORTANT: pour faciliter nos échanges comptables, lors de votre paiement, par chèque et en particul
ier par virement, merci de rappeler votre n° de client et n° de facture acquittée.

Paiement comptant sans escompte même en cas de paiement anticipé. Au-delà de 10 jours, une pénalité
de 3 fois le taux d'intérêt légal (Loi 2008-776 du 04 août 2008) sera appliquée, calculée au prorata
 temporis sur la valeur de facture.

Conforment à la loi du 29 février 2012 le montant de l'indemnité forfaitaire pour frais de recouvrem
ent est de 40 euros dans le cas où les sommes dues sont réglées après la date de règlement figurant
sur la facture.


SQL>
```